# mongodb $unwind for non-ideal nested document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm aware that the below mongodb document may not be in an ideal structure, but is there any way to unwind that `$rounds.round_values`?

I've tried with `aggregate([{"$unwind": "$rounds"}])`, or `"$rounds.round_values"` but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bea750c26a1c7095387d00"), 
    "rounds" : [
        {
            "round_number" : "0", 
            "round_values" : {
                "max_player_pot" : "0.25", 
                "pot_multiple" : "0.625", 
               
        }, 
        {
            "round_number" : "1", 
            "round_values" : {
                "max_player_pot" : "0.0", 
                "pot_multiple" : "0.0", 
        }
    ], 
    "GameID" : "392124717", 
    "ComputerName" : "awdfadf", 

}
```

Expected output:

```
{ 
    "max_player_pot" : "0.25", 
    "pot_multiple" : "0.625", 
    "GameID" : "392124717", 
    "ComputerName" : "awdfadf", 
},
{
    "max_player_pot" : "0.0", 
    "pot_multiple" : "0.0", 
    "GameID" : "392124717", 
    "ComputerName" : "awdfadf", 
}
```

Comment: what is the exact problem? it is working perfectly see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ARpuSiJyYLN).

Comment: I see. Yes true it unwinds it, but how can I flatten the whole structure to have directly the round_values on top level?

Comment: can you please show your expected result for more clear picture?

Comment: edited question to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct the rounds array
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$rounds" },
  {
    $project: {
      GameID: 1,
      ComputerName: 1,
      max_player_pot: "$rounds.round_values.max_player_pot",
      pot_multiple: "$rounds.round_values.pot_multiple"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hPRxYDIJOMV)

---

A more dynamic approach,

- `$mergeObjects` to merge required fields from root and `round_values` object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above merged object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$rounds" },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            GameID: "$GameID",
            ComputerName: "$ComputerName"
          },
          "$rounds.round_values"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-lHO5O0RCHq)

Comment: ok great that works, but I have around 300 entries in rounds. Any way I can avoid typing them all? thanks

Comment: i have updated the answer with second solution.